# Customize XCTest report XML files

Tags: xctest, xcodebuild

I'm running XCode UI tests from the command line, and recording the results into a junit XML file, like this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ./myapp.xcworkspace -scheme myapp-XCUITests -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=12.4,name=iPad Air' test | xcpretty --report junit --output '~/myapp/test_output/report.junit'
```

Is there a way to add custom attributes to the .junit files? This is what a typical test case looks like:

```
<testcase classname='myapp.LoginScreenUITests' name='test_12345_ErrorMessage'>
```

I don't like embedding the test case ID in the test name... I would prefer something like `<testcase testcaseId="12345" ...>`